# Does pow() work for int data type in C?

Tags: c, pow, exponentiation

I was simply writing a program to calculate the power of an integer. But the output was not as expected. It worked for all the integer numbers except for the **power of 5.**

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a,b;
  printf("Enter the number.");
  scanf("\n%d",&a);
  b=pow(a,2);
  printf("\n%d",b);
}
```

The output is something like this:

```
"Enter the number. 2
 4
"Enter the number. 5
 24
"Enter the number. 4
 16
"Enter the number. 10
 99
```

Can't we use `pow()` function for int data type??

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/SHxi5B). Also, it's `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Comment: @AndyG; It is not necessary you will get the same result as OP gets on his machine. Question is good. Upvoted to counter downvotes.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what's with all the down votes. Simple question, yet I'm stumped.

Comment: Before posting a question, you should try to answer by searching. This question doesn't show any research effort

Comment: Why the hell ppl down vote answer without giving chance for somebody to justify or modify answer? FOLLOW SO RULES PPPL!!!!!!

Comment: @haccks: The compiler should produce the usual arithmetic conversions and cast `a` to `double` for the `pow` function, no?

Comment: @GRC - if an answer is wrong, it gets downvoted. That's totally reasonable. If the author fixes it, hopefully the downvotes will be removed.

Comment: @CarlNorum You should make a comment below and wait until author replies at least, that is the rule, do not be rude.

Comment: @GRC Respectfully, please read this section of Stack Overflow on down votes : http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @Cubia read last sentence **If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.** That way you are helping the poster of an answer learn as well.

Comment: @GRG I have read it, it is not a rule, it is an alternative. Please do not enforce fake rules, it is completely reasonable to down vote an answer without giving somebody the chance to justify it. If you need to justify your answer in a comment, this means that your answer is incomplete anyway.

Comment: Regarding downvotes, I would say a comment would always be appreciated. Sometimes users misread the question and post his/her answer. By pointing his mistakes in the given answer you are not only informing that poster but to the users who visit that answer and really don't know why it is downvoted or is a wrong answer.

Comment: @haccks: Thank you for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Floating point precision is doing its job here. The actual working of `pow` is using `log`

```
pow(a, 2) ==> exp(log(a) * 2)
```

Look at `math.h` library which says:
###`<math.h>`

> /* Excess precision when using a 64-bit mantissa for FPU math ops can
> cause unexpected results with some of the MSVCRT math functions.  For
> example, unless the function return value is stored (truncating to
> 53-bit mantissa), calls to pow with both x and y as integral values
> sometimes produce a non-integral result. ... */

Just add `0.5` to the return value of `pow` and then convert it to `int`.

```
b = (int)(pow(a,2) + 0.5);
```

So, the answer to your question

> Does pow() work for `int` data type in C?

Not always. For integer exponentiation you could implement your own function (this will work for 0 and +ve `exp` only):

```
unsigned uint_pow(unsigned base, unsigned exp)
{
    unsigned result = 1;
    while (exp)
    {
        if (exp % 2)
           result *= base;
        exp /= 2;
        base *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding on what you mean by "Floating point precision is doing its job"? Why is pow() returning the wrong value? I would expect that when an int is passed to a parameter of type double, the double would receive an exact value (5 => 5.0000000...)?

Comment: Then why is it only for multiples of 5???

Comment: @basanta I want to say that it's because it's an odd number maybe? I can't replicate the problem, so I'm just guessing here.

Comment: @Cubia; http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: @haccks Thank you for the great explanation in your answer + the documentation. Appreciate it

Comment: a good `pow` implementation would check if the exponent is int to do the other way and get the more correct result

Comment: But isn't 100 is perfectly representable in double

Comment: Curious code uses  `exp & 1` and `exp /= 2` here.  `exp % 2` and `exp /= 2` would be more symmetric (and fix otherwise broken code for ancient ones` complement).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Feel free to edit if code is broken or needs improvement.

Comment: @haccks Hope it passes your review.  Although a minor UB remains: `result *= base;` and `base *= base;` may `int` overflow.  Leave that detection for another day or go for `unsigned unsigned_pow(unsigned base, unsigned exp)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks and you are welcome for any suggestions and edits.

Answer (score 4):

there is no int based pow.  What you are suffering from is floating point truncation.

an int based pow is too constrained (the range of inputs would quickly overflow an int).  In many cases int based pow, like in your case where its powers of 2 can be done efficiently other ways.

Comment: is floating point truncation just for the multiples of 5??

Comment: you are going to hit it on various numbers.

Answer (score 3):

`printf("%a", pow(10, 2))` and see what you get; I expect you'll see you don't *quite* get 100. Call `lround` if you want to round instead of truncating.

Answer (score 1):

The C library function double pow(double x, double y)

It takes double type

Comment: This question is about `C`

Comment: Undelete this post!!!!

Comment: This does not even attempt to explain OP's "But the output was not as expected".