# c++ to_string was not declared in this scope error [Windows + Devcpp environment]

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, tostring

I am trying to implement the Karatsuba multiplication algorithm in c++ on Windows 10 using Devcpp ide. Here is the code for the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int karatsuba(int x, int y){
    string sx = to_string(x);
    string sy = to_string(y);
    int len_x = strlen(sx);
    int len_y = strlen(sy);
    if (len_x == 1 && len_y == 1)
        return x * y;
    else{
        int n = max(len_x, len_y);
        int n_by_2 = n / 2;

        int a = x / pow(10, n_by_2);
        int b = x % pow(10, n_by_2);
        int c = y / pow(10, n_by_2);
        int d = y % pow(10, n_by_2);

        int ac = karatsuba(a, c);
        int bd = karatsuba(b, d);

        int ad_plus_bc = karatsuba(a+b, c+d);
        int prod = ac * pow(10, n_by_2) + (ad_plus_bc * pow(10, n_by_2)) + bd;
        return prod;
    }
}

int main(){
    cout<<karatsuba(45, 45);
}
```

When I run this program I get these errors:

C:\Users\AKuro\Desktop\C++\Divide and Conquer\karatsuba.cpp In function 'int karatsuba(int, int)':
7   25  C:\Users\AKuro\Desktop\C++\Divide and Conquer\karatsuba.cpp [Error] 'to_string' was not declared in this scope

9   23  C:\Users\AKuro\Desktop\C++\Divide and Conquer\karatsuba.cpp [Error] 'strlen' was not declared in this scope

18  29  C:\Users\AKuro\Desktop\C++\Divide and Conquer\karatsuba.cpp [Error] invalid operands of types 'int' and '__gnu_cxx::__promote_2::__type {aka double}' to binary 'operator%'

20  29  C:\Users\AKuro\Desktop\C++\Divide and Conquer\karatsuba.cpp [Error] invalid operands of types 'int' and '__gnu_cxx::__promote_2::__type {aka double}' to binary 'operator%'

I tried the methods I found through Googling but none of them seem to work. Here is what I have already tried:

using std with to_string as such std::to_string

I have even tried this approach

```
int i = 1212;
stringstream ss;
ss << i;
string s=ss.str();
```

but none seems to work and I couldn't find any answer to this particular environment (Windows 10 + Devcpp). It has been really bugging me. Please if you could help me out.

Comment: Did you set -std=c++11 in your IDE?

Comment: What compiler options are you using? What exactly do you mean by "*none seems to work*" (any errors)?

Comment: `std::string` has `.size()` function, use it instead of `strlen` (which works only on string literals: "qwe")

Comment: Enable [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951376/how-to-change-mode-from-c98-mode-in-dev-c-to-a-mode-that-supports-c0x-ran)

Comment: Also be aware of rounding when using `std::pow` with integer values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787310/does-pow-work-for-int-data-type-in-c

Comment: ... or preferably just use `sx.length()`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors here:

1) `to_string()` is a [c++11 feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). So make sure you set -std=c++11 in your makefile or IDE.

2) `strlen()` is declared in `cstring`, not `string`. Better way here is to use something like `int len_x = sx.size();`, and similar for the other string.

3) Return type of `pow()` is [float or double](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow). So you need to cast it expicitly like this: `int b = x % static_cast<int>(pow(10, n_by_2));`. You need to do this for all expressions which use `pow()` and assign result to `int` variable. Actually, even better than casting would be to write your own simple `intpow()` function, which is not hard to do (it is so simple that the standard seems to have skipped it :-) ).

Comment: Thank you mahesh this really helped me out...was struggling with it for quite a while