# Multiplying and increasing pows

Tags: c, for-loop, pow, multiplication

Idea is this: http://prntscr.com/m0xopk  , It works perfectly except 5, when i give 5 it calculates wrong.I can't understand why?

```
int i,a,n;
int sum = 1;

scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",&n);


for(i = 1;i <= n;i++){
     sum *=pow(a,i);

}
printf("%d",sum);
```

Comment: [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) is a floating point function, and as such have the same problems as all floating point arithmetic have on computers and is discussed in [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) For integers I suggest you make up your own function instead, but beware of overflows.

Comment: It's an  assignment before  functions so i didin't use functions,thanks for your answer

Comment: Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Edit your question to give us the *full* input that makes it fail, and tell us the expected and actual output.

Comment: For `a=5` and `n=5` the result is `30517578125` which is too large for a 32-bit `int`. Try `double sum = 1;` and `printf("%f",sum);`

Comment: You can avoid calling `pow`, by calculating one power from the previous power: a^n = a^(n-1) * a

Answer (score 0):

> It works perfectly except 5, when i give 5 it calculates wrong

No, it works perfectly for values *less* than `5`. When you give input `5` for both `a` and `n`, the summation resultant number will be `30517578125` which is big for `32` bit `int` type variable to hold. Instead, you should use `uint64_t` type variable.

Also, you should not use `pow()` function for integer type. Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787310/does-pow-work-for-int-data-type-in-c).

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    int i, a, n;
    uint64_t num = 1, result = 1;;

    printf ("Enter a: \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf ("Enter n: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        num = num * a;
        result = num * result;
    }

    printf("result: %"PRId64"\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this `64` bit solution is also having a limit and will work for input `5` but may not be for a number little bigger than `5`. If you want arbitrarily large number, check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252896/how-do-you-store-an-arbitrarily-large-integer-value-in-memory).

Answer (score 0):

Integers cant accommodate so large numbers. You need to use float numbers instead.

```
double calc(double a, int i)
{
    double sum = 1;

    for(int p = 1; p <= i; p++)
    {
        sum *= pow(a,i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```