# Get Integer input and output it line by line without an array

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, integer-division

I am trying to write a c program when I input an integer using `scanf` and split that integer number and print it line by line without an array. I can show you example how I am going to do that.

```
123 / 100 = 1
123 % 100 = 23

23 / 10 = 2
23 % 19 = 3

1
2
3
```

I know how to do that but the problem is when I run this code 
.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    int no, a;
    int count, new;
    int newNum = 0;

    printf("Enter an intger number = ");
    scanf("%d", &no);

    newNum = no;
    printf("You entered = %d\n", newNum);

    while(newNum != 0){
        newNum = newNum / 10;
        count++;
    }

    count--;
    count = pow(10, count);

    printf("Power of ten = %d\n", count);

    while(count != 1){
        new = no / count;
        no = no % count;
        printf("%d\n", new);
        count = count / 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter an intger number = 123
You entered = 123
Power of ten = -2147483648
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-5
-9
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Problem is power of ten line did not output right value But If I comment second while loop section.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    int no;
    int count, new;
    int newNum = 0;

    printf("Enter an intger number = ");
    scanf("%d", &no);

    newNum = no;
    printf("You entered = %d\n", newNum);

    while(newNum != 0){
        newNum = newNum / 10;
        count++;
    }

    count--;
    count = pow(10, count);

    printf("Power of ten = %d\n", count);

//  while(count != 1){
//      new = no / count;
//      no = no % count;
//      printf("%d\n", new);
//      count = count / 10;
//  }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter an intger number = 123
You entered = 123
Power of ten = 100
```

**This time Power of ten shows the correct value.**

What can I do to avoid this issue?

and

- Is there any way to do this without using arrays?

Comment: You do `count++` while `count` is uninitialized and have an indeterminate value.

Comment: _Is there any way to do this without using arrays_...? You are not using arrays...Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I have done silly mistake that programmer won't do. Is there a any other code to do my work. I do this using '%' to get my output. Is there any way to do that work without `%`.

Comment: Why would you want to do it without `%`? What exactly are you trying to achieve or what is the exact requirement you are trying to meet? If you use recursion you can do it in about 5 lines of code (still uses `%` though).

Comment: Is my code is the only code which can achieve that result without using arrays? **or** is there a different way

Comment: As I said, you can use recursion.

Comment: `void p(int i) { if (!i) return; p(i/10); printf("%d\n",i%10); }`

Comment: I can use `Fibonacci Series`. That's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you should be caution and not to make an overflow calculating the power of 10.

Always test your program for boundary values as for example `INT_MAX` or `UINT_MAX`.

There is no need to use mathematical functions.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const unsigned int Base = 10;

        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        unsigned int divisor = 1; 

        for ( unsigned int tmp = n; !( tmp < Base ); tmp /= Base )
        {
            divisor *= Base;;
        }

        printf( "%u\n", n / divisor );

        for ( ; divisor != 1; divisor /= Base )
        {
            printf( "%u\n", n % divisor / ( divisor / Base ) );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1
1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10
1
0

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 123456789
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4294967295
4
2
9
4
9
6
7
2
9
5

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Another approach is to use a recursive function as shown here

```
#include <stdio.h>

void output_digits( unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    unsigned int digit = n % Base;

    if ( ( n /= Base ) != 0 ) output_digits( n );

    printf( "%u\n", digit );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        output_digits( n );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is an answer I was looking for. Thank you very much for sharing this. I wish both answers can be accpeted

Answer (score 3):

In your code variable `count` has local scope (automatic storage duration).

Local scope variables are not initialized due to their stack allocation.

```
int count=0;
```

(C99 standard) section 6.7.8 clause 10:

> **If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.**
>
> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
> - if it is a union, the ﬁrst named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.

Note: you should avoid to use `new` as a name of a variable.

Comment: I have done silly mistake that programmer won't do. Is there a any other code to do my work. I do this using '%' to get my output. without that can it be done?

Comment: @Kalana I'm not getting you. Do you mean`%` as `printf` format specifier?..

Comment: @LPs I think OP means modulo.

Comment: It is hard to explain. is my code is the only code which can achive that result without using arrays?

Comment: @Kalana It depends on what you means with array. You could use strings (that are arrays using [tag:c]) and related funtion (like strlen). Anyway your implementation is the standard (faster) implementation to count digits of an integer number.

Comment: sorry for bothering you, Thank you very much @LPs

Answer (score 1):

You want to print each digit of a base10 number.
The number of digit can be retrieved with this simple formula

```
int n_digit = (int)log10(x) +1;
```

To test it: `(int)log10(99) +1 = (int)1.9956 +1 = 2` and `(int)log10(100) +1 = (int)2 +1 = 3`

So you want to print the quotients of each power of 10:

```
for(int i=n_digit-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    // Calc 10^i without pow function
    int num_10_pow_i = 1;
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        num_10_pow_i *=10;

    printf("N[%d]=",i);
    printf("%d\n", (int)(x/num_10_pow_i));
    x = x-((int)(x/num_10_pow_i) * num_10_pow_i);
}
```

Please don't use the `pow` function working with integers.

Read here for more info:
[Does pow() work for int data type in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787310/does-pow-work-for-int-data-type-in-c)

Comment: Yes, I can understand, Thank you @G. C.

Comment: `(int)log10(x)` (as well as `pow()` for like reasons) is prone to round-off error and so fail code.  Better to avoid floating point math for an integer problem.  `(int)log10(x)` is also a problem when `x==0`.

Answer (score 1):

In my program I have set my integer variables equal to 0 like this.

```
int no, a = 0;
int count = 0, new = 0;
int newNum = 0;
```

After that my program works perfectly, but **didn't get the full output**. That problem came from this section

```
while(count != 1){
    new = no / count;
    no = no % count;
    printf("%d\n", new);
    count = count / 10;
}
```

**Output -:**

```
Enter an intger number = 123
You entered = 123
Power of ten = 100
1
2
```

You can see `3` **didn't in output section**. There for I have add extra line outside of the while loop to get my expected output. I have add a following.

```
while(count != 1){
    new = no / count;
    no = no % count;
    printf("%d\n", new);
    count = count / 10;
}
printf("%d\n", no);
```

**Output -:**

```
Enter an intger number = 123
You entered = 123
Power of ten = 100
1
2
3
```

Now it is completed.