# push_back(value) is automatically reduced by 1

Tags: c++, stl, implementation

Consider the following code:

```
int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        int num,i,ct=0;
        vector<int> summ;
        i=0;
        while(n)
        {
           if(n%10)
           {
               cout<<(n%10)*pow(10,i)<<" ";
               summ.push_back((n%10)*pow(10,i));    ct++;
           }
           i++;
           n=n/10;
        }
        cout<<'\n'<<ct<<'\n';
        for(i=0;i<summ.size();i++)
        {
            cout<<summ[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    }
```

If I give the following input:

```
1
555
```

The output produced is **5 50 500 3 5 50 499**.

I don't understand why the numbers change on push_back().

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: I tried to replicate this issue and was un-successful. https://godbolt.org/z/fFTCVP

Comment: The output I got is `5 50 500 3 5 50 500` https://onlinegdb.com/BysVlsM6U

Comment: *"Can someone please explain why this is happening? "* -- in the interest of fairness and sharing the burden here, could you please explain what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: I have been able to reproduce `5 50 500 3 5 50 499` on `GNU GCC` 32-bit Windows. The difference appears to be due to rounding, as setting `summ` as vector<double> rather than vector<int> gives the last integer as 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the use of `pow`. You should be storing the result as either a float or a double, as storing directly into an int is causing the imprecision. This seemingly strange behaviour [is well known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787310/does-pow-work-for-int-data-type-in-c). This behaviour appears to vary depending on your compiler.

To correct this, change your `vector<int> summ` to `vector<float> summ` or `double`. Alternatively, create a temporary `float` or `double` variable which is then placed into the vector after the calculation is done.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```cpp
    cout << (n % 10) * pow(10, i) << " ";
```

you are printing a `double` value: the *integer* `(n % 10)` is converted to a `double` because the `pow()` function returns a `double`.

However, in the line:

```cpp
    summ.push_back((n % 10) * pow(10, i));
```

the calculated value (also a `double`) is ***truncated*** to an `int` before being placed in the vector, because you have declared it to be a `std::vector<int>`.

So, you *may* get an error (very occasionally) if the calculated `double` is even *minutely* less than the expected 'integral' value. (See: [Strange behaviour of the pow function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18155883/10871073).) Printing the calculated values to full precision will show you if this is, in fact, the case:

```cpp
    cout << std::setprecision(20) << std::fixed << (n % 10) * pow(10, i) << " ";
```

A 'quick fix' in this case would be to add `0.5` to the calculated value *before* it is truncated and pushed:

```cpp
    summ.push_back((n % 10) * pow(10, i) + 0.5);
```