# Linear Recursion Vectorization

Tags: c, python-3.x, performance, vectorization, comparison-operators

To vectorize the following mathematical expression (linear recursion):

```
f(i)=f(i-1)/c+g(i), i starts at 1, f(0), c are constant numbers and given.
```

I can get better speed by using list-comprehension, that is:

```
def function():
        txt=     [0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,2]  
        indices_0=[]
        vl=0
        sb_l=10
        CONST=512
        [vl := vl+pow(txt[i],(i+1)) for i in range(sb_l)]
        if (vl==1876):
                        indices_0=[0]
        p=[i for i in range(1,len(txt)-sb_l+1) if (vl := (vl-txt[i-1])/2+ txt[i+sb_l-1]*CONST)==1876]
        print(indices_0+p)

function()
```

I am looking for a vectorized/faster than vectorization (if possible!) implementation of the above code in python/c.

Note:

1.

A linear recursive function is a function that only makes a single call to itself each time the function runs (as opposed to one that would call itself multiple times during its execution). The factorial function is a good example of linear recursion.

2.

Note that all variables array are given for demonstration purpose, the main part for vectorization is :

```
[vl := vl+pow(txt[i],(i+1)) for i in range(sb_l)]
if (vl==1876):
            indices_0=[0]
            p=[i for i in range(1,len(txt)-sb_l+1) 
                 if (vl := (vl-txt[i-1])/2+ txt[i+sb_l-1]*CONST)==1876]
```

Here, `f(i-1)= (vl-txt[i-1]), c=2,  g(i)= txt[i+sb_l-1]*CONST`.

POSTSCRIPT: I am currently doing it in python, would it be much faster if it is implemented in `C` language's vectorization?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is this the only question - "would it be much faster if it implemented in C language's vectorization?"

Comment: Short answer: yes, C will be far faster than the CPython interpreter (or any other Python interpreter actually). Not much a surprise. Actually, Python is not designed to run such a code efficiently. Note that your number can grow pretty quickly. C does not provide native large integer (at least not wider than 64-bit which is already large). Consider using a library if the number can be big (eg. few billions).

Comment: I think recursion will need to be converted into iteration to utilize vectorization. And yes, it will probably be faster in C.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I am looking for a faster implementation, it could be python/c/vectorization..anything that compute posted function fast.

Comment: @JérômeRichard it would be helpful if you can provide a c implementation, it could be a good example for learning purpose even with the integer size limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of equivalent C program doing the same thing but faster:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787310/does-pow-work-for-int-data-type-in-c
int64_t int_pow(int64_t base, int exp)
{
    int64_t result = 1;
    while (exp)
    {
        // Branchless optimization: result *= base * (exp % 2);
        if(exp % 2)
            result *= base;
        exp /= 2;
        base *= base;
    }
    return result;
}

void function()
{
    // Both txt values and sb_l not be too big or it will cause silent overflows (ie. wrong results)
    const int64_t txt[] = {0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,2};
    const size_t txtSize = sizeof(txt) / sizeof(txt[0]);
    const int sb_l = 10;
    const int64_t CONST = 512;
    int64_t vl = 0;
    int64_t* results = (int64_t*)malloc(txtSize * sizeof(int64_t));
    size_t cur = 0;

    // Optimization so not to compute pow(0,i+1) which is 0
    for (int i = 0; i < sb_l; ++i)
        if(txt[i] != 0)
            vl += int_pow(txt[i], i+1);

    if (vl == 1876)
    {
        results[cur] = 0;
        cur++;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < txtSize-sb_l+1; ++i)
    {
        vl = (vl - txt[i-1]) / 2 + txt[i+sb_l-1] * CONST;

        if(vl == 1876)
            results[cur++] = i;
    }

    // Printing
    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < cur; ++i)
    {
        if(i > 0)
            printf(", ");
        printf("%ld", results[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    free(results);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

Be careful with overflows. You can put assertions if you are unsure about that in specific places (note they make the code slower when enabled though). Please do not forget to compile the program with optimizations (eg. `-O3` with GCC and Clang and `/O2` with MSVC).

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but it looks like a simple c implementation, not vectorized, I was asking about vectorization in c language, could you refer me to a tutorial notes/introductory notes on c vectorization, where I can learn and vectorize this code (in c), I am completely new to c vectorization, thanks for your feedback, up-voted.

Comment: Python and C does not work the same way. Python is generally interpreted and very dynamic (which basically mean the execution of instructions are very slow). To write efficient codes, developers needs to use C modules that are compiled and generally optimized so few (cheap) function calls does all the work. When dealing with arrays, Python developers should use library like Numpy, avoid loops like the plague because of the CPython interpreter and instead use "vectorized" functions. Such functions are basic C ones and are sometimes but not always using SIMD instructions.

Comment: In C, loops are very fast. The compiler is able to *automatically vectorize* the loops so to use SIMD instructions. The term "vectorize" refer to different meaning in C and Python: in C it means the code can use SIMD instructions and in Python it means the code use a C implementation. The automatic vectorization is not a silverbullet but compilers are quite good to do that for basic loops. Developers can use SIMD intrinsics and assembly code so to manually force the use of SIMD instructions but this is nor portable and makes the code very hard to head.

Comment: In this specific case, the compiler should not generate SIMD instruction, and this is normal because this is very hard to vectorize the code efficiently due to the data-dependence. In fact, there is AFAIK no way to efficiently efficient use SIMD instructions in this case on x86-64 processors supporting the SSE-X/AVX/AVX-2 instruction sets. That being said, this should be find: the call to `function()` should last for no more than 0.001 ms at most on a mainstream PC (in fact most of the time should be spent in the malloc/free).

Comment: Put it shortly: loops are fine in (compiled) C, but not in (interpreted) Python. This code should be very fast.

Comment: If `txt` only contains `0` and `2`, then `pow(txt[i], i+1) == (txt[i]/2) << (i+1) == txt[i] << i` which can vectorize with AVX2